# given the function f(x,y)= $(x^2+y^2)e^{y^2-x^2}$ what is the partial derivative with respect to x?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I got $$2x e^{(y^2-x^2)}-(2x^3-2xy^2)e^{(y^2-x^2)}$$ is this correct? This in relation to trying to find maximum and minimum values with partial derivatives.

Comment: As far as I can see, this is correct except for the minus (-) in the $(2x^3-2xy^2) $ expression should be a plus (+).

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not but it is very close!  You have one sign wrong.  The derivative is $2xe^{y^2- x^2}+ (-2x^3- 2xy^2)e^{y^2- x^2}$ or, equivalently, $2xe^{y^2- x^2}- (2x^3+ 2xy^2)e^{y^2- x^2}$

Comment: Okay thank you! That makes more sense with the chain rule bringing down the derivative of $$ -x^2 $$